# Exposing a Django Application Inside Docker to a Public IP Address

Tags: django, docker, networking

I would like to ensure that I'm taking the right steps to expose my Django application running inside a Docker container to a public IP address. Here's the current setup:

1. The Django application is running within a Docker container.
2. Docker is installed on a Linux server, which also has a public IP
   address.
3. The following command is used in the entrypoint.sh file, which will
   be invoked by the Docker Compose file to start the application:

```
exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:${PORT:-8000} --timeout 120 wtools2.wsgi:application
```

If there are any missing pieces I should consider, please provide your guidance.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing piece is exposing your 8000 port from inside the container to the Docker host server and this can be done by docker expose/publish

```
docker run -p 0.0.0.0:80:8000/tcp $IMAGE_NAME
```

This will export port 8000 from docker to port 80 on the host and can be reached on all networks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I also use 8080 OR 8005 instead of 80?

Comment: Sure, it is just for example purposes